# XML parser: implementation design

Tags: c#, xml

I've always assumed XML documents are a convenient way to store information. Now I've found in XML a good way to "instruct" my application. Delicous.

My problem is integrate the XML parsing in application classes. I'm using C# System.Xml interface, I think it's good and portable (right?).

Is there any standard interface which defines methods to organize recursion on xml tags, or methods to implement common xml implementations (maybe in a base class)?

Initially I can think to write an interface which defines

```
void Read(XmlReader xml);

void Write(XmlREader xml);
```

What what about nested tags, common tags and so on...

P.S.: I don't think to implement this using LINQ, except in the case it's supported also in Mono (how to determine this)?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Why not use configuration files?

Comment: XML can be extended easily by adding another element or attribute. Allow to ignore unknown elements (or attributes), improving compatibility with previous application versions. XML is easy to understand and to write. It can represents many structures, from list to trees.

My problem is how to design application to best support object serialization. Now I'm investigating on Binary Worrier tip. It's a good solution, but the XmlSerializer doesn't allow private fields storage, while XmlReader allow more control over XML parsing (but requires more code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization(VS.71).aspx), this is a beginners [Tutorial on Serialization](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file)

Comment: I'm thinking to write a proxy parser (using XmlReader), which calls methods of a ipothetic IMyXmlObject interaface, which handle elements and attributes. The handling is implemented in IMyXmlObject implementor, which acquire data using the interface implementation.

Serialization is a good solution, but it is not what I'm looking for. I must have the possibility to execute actions depending on how XML is written.

Other advices?

Answer (score 0):

As Binary Worrier mentioned, XML serialization is a simple and efficient option. You can also use Linq to XML, which is supported in Mono [since version 2.0](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.0) (released in october 2008)

Answer (score 0):

Using xml to "instruct" your app seems backwards to me. I'd be more inclined to use an IronPython script if that was my aim. Xml, normally, is intended to serialize *data*. Sure you can *write* a language via xml, but ultimately it is fighting the system. You would also massively struggle to invoke *methods* (easy enough to set properties etc via `XmlSerializer`, though).

Here's [A 3 minute guide to embedding IronPython in a C# application](http://www.secretgeek.net/host_ironpython.asp) to show what might, IMO, be a better way to "instruct" a C# application via a separate script file.